# Asking admission committee to confirm if they received my application and letters

Tags: graduate-admissions, etiquette, application

I'm applying to a PhD program and the application isn't centralized or anything. I don't upload the required documents to a server, I just send them as emails attachments. Is it kosher to ask them to confirm if they have correctly received my documents as well as the recommendation letters my references have sent them?

Comment: Don't bother the committee, just email or call one of the department administrators/program coordinators.

Comment: You could definitely ask for an acknowledgement. I must add, it is wise to ask for an acknowledgement along with the application and not after it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you should ask whomever it is that you emailed the documents to. You can either ask them to respond in the email with the attachments, or follow up later asking if they received everything. A polite way of doing so might be something like:

> Hi Prof. Dexter,
>
> I wanted check that you received my transcript and personal statement which I sent on Feb 30. You should have also received three letters of recommendation for me from Profs Dyer, Ellery, and Freeborn. Please let me know if any of these have not arrived and if there are any other documents you needed from me. I'm very excited to be applying to Miskatonic U.
>
> Thank you for your time,
>
> Ululu

Answer (score 1):

Students should **absolutely** contact someone in the departments to which they apply to see if all materials have been received.  A departmental secretary is the appropriate point of contact for this.  The reason is that parts of applications are misplaced just by virtue of the amount of paper being shuffled and incomplete applications may not be evaluated.